# Android Load Json from file Error

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I am building am app the will work offline.

I download the json to a file in the sdcard. then when I try and load it using gson and map it with POJO class I get error:

read the file:

```
File newList = new File(rootFolder.getParent(), "custom_list.new.dat");
String customListStr = Utils.readTextFile(newList);



    public static String readTextFile(File file) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream reader = new FileInputStream(file);
        StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer("");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (reader.read(buffer) != -1)
            data.append(new String(buffer));
        reader.close();
        return data.toString();
    }



try to load it

//Load json file to Model
                    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                    final MoviePojo response = gson.fromJson(customListStr, MoviePojo.class);
                    int size = response.getContentList().size();
```

> > : Error: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 3205 path $

Answer (score 0):

The error shows you, in the text, that the JSON you have downloaded has an error in its structure `MalformedJsonException`, "Malformed". Check the JSON file, from top to bottom, may be some of this `("{", "[", ",", ":" )` characters are missing or has more than the quantity it needs.

Good luck.

Comment: I just checked it. It is a valid json

Comment: Make this test: Copy the contect of your json file and paste it as the value of the variable "customListStr". Comment the line where you crate a File object, and run your code if the error is shown again.